# Buenas! Subi un proyecto que realice en DH a github Pages pero no se muestra, no se cual es el error, Dejo el repo

Tags: github, github-pages

Este es mi repo si pueden ayudarme https://github.com/AmaliaRibeiro/amaliaribeiro.github.io

Comment: Hola Amalia, te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Por favor revisa [ask] para recibir mejores respuestas. Tambien te invito a que realices el [tour] para que entiendas cómo funciona el sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla.

Comment: Explica un poco tu problema y claro puedes colocar ese link , por que si no va ser mal recibida tu pregunta

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Redacta la pregunta de manera que sea útil no solo para ti, sino también para otros usuarios que lleguen a tener un problema similar más adelante. Los detalles del problema deben estar en la pregunta misma. Pulsa en [edit] para corregirla.

Comment: El [sitio](https://amaliaribeiro.github.io/) si se muestra. ¿Querrás decir: *Por qué solo se muestra el **readme.md***? Como en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48919200/13419694) del sitio en inglés.